# Visual Studio Team Services error: "The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system."

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

When I try to deploy my artifact on IIS, I am getting the error as shown in the below screenshot. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

The **"IIS Web App Management"** screenshot is shown below:

[image]

Comment: How did you define task `IIS Web App Management`? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Yeah Sure. I have edited my question and added the screenshot for "IIS Web App Management". Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: You can't use it to install IIS on a client OS (such as Windows 10). You have to use a server OS (such as Windows Server).

There's nothing you can do about it other than to use a server OS or use an [alternate tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) to deploy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to VSTS and have been frustrated with this issue from past two days.

Comment: Indeed VSTS cannot install IIS on a client OS. But you can manually install IIS on the client OS and then use VSTS to deploy to a Client OS!

Just uncheck the 'Enable IIS' option and the deploy succeeds!

Answer (score 0):

> Using Windows Remote Management (WinRM), connect to the host
>   machine(s) where IIS or SQL Server is installed, and manage the Web
>   application or deploy the SQL Server Database as described below:
>
> - Create a new website or update an existing website using AppCmd.exe.
> - Create a new application pool or update an existing application pool    using AppCmd.exe.
> - Deploy a Web Application to the IIS Server using Web Deploy.
> - Deploy a SQL Server Database using DACPAC and SqlPackage.exe.

Your log mentioned the task was installing IIS, and it seemed the tasking was installing IIS on a windows client OS. You need to check your target machine to see whether it has IIS installed.